# How do I count how many times strings from a list appear each in a query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So basically, I have a list of distinct names, lets say

`John`
`Mary`
`Pedro`

And I have a query that returns `John John Mary Pedro Mary John Pedro Mary Mary`

I'd like a query that takes both of these and returns

`John` `3`

`Mary` `4`

`Pedro` `2`

But I've absolutely no idea how do do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be pretty straight-forward.

You need to use an aggregate function `COUNT()` to count the number of instances for every name.

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS totalCount
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bc53/2)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more way of writing SQL query :

```
SELECT Name, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) as "occurrence" from yourTable;
```

Here analytic function is used to find the count of names in the table.

Comment: This will return 3 rows for John, whereas the OP (at least as far as I understand it) wants only 1 row per name.

Comment: that's true @FrankSchmitt , just wanted to put some light on other possibilities.